# Issue with Passenger, nginx and Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I'm running nginx and passenger to host a Rails 3.2.22 site. It was working just fine up until recently, but the latest deploy has stumbled across some sort of bug.

nginx/passenger won't start up properly due to the following error:

```
App 1542 stderr: /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:156:in `select'
App 1542 stderr: :
App 1542 stderr: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
App 1542 stderr:  (
App 1542 stderr: ArgumentError
App 1542 stderr: )
App 1542 stderr:        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:483:in `wait_until_termination_requested'
App 1542 stderr:        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:202:in `main_loop'
App 1542 stderr:        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:159:in `<module:App>'
App 1542 stderr:        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 1542 stderr:        from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.23/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

It looks like Passenger is calling an action_view helper for 'select', for reasons I don't understand. The action_view helper at line 156 looks as follows:

```
def select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {})
  InstanceTag.new(object, method, self, options.delete(:object)).to_select_tag(choices, options, html_options)
end
```

The caller in passenger (request_helper line 483) looks like this:

```
ios = select([@owner_pipe, @graceful_termination_pipe[0]])[0]
```

Which is most likely a completely different 'select' call. I can't figure out why passenger is invoking the call for the ActionView helper (which is a form select).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was related to my use of embedded ruby and **Resque** jobs. I have a delayed-execution job which performs a piece of work based on an ERb template. In order to be able to access some of the **ERb** helper methods, I included the following code:

```
include ActionView::Helpers
```

Unfortunately, I'd put this at the top of the file (similar to *require*) instead of inside the Generator class. Moving the statement inside the class definition resolved the problem.

It would appear that **Passenger** was including the job file (even though it was in a separate *app/jobs* directory and only really for use by **Resque**) and this was playing havoc with some of the Passenger function definitions.